# Bootstrap: Responsive not working on phone altough viewport included

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My bootstrap pages are designed responsively. The viewport is stated as required:

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`
```

(without the backticks)

In browsers I tested (Safari, Chrome, Firefox), the responsivity works well.

However, iPhones and other smarthphones always show the desktop view.

What am I doing wrong? This is a test page for you to see (sorry it's still a little cluttered):
http://zhaw.warnez-services.ch/NaKt/stackoverflow.php (LINK UPDATED)

Interestingly, using a Cloaking service, they send their own head and suppress my viewport instructions.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Viewport tag is not yet added.

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` inside the `<head></head>` of your HTML/PHP.

Comment: Beat me by seconds! +1

Comment: Thanks, but no, it is included. But the cloaking service I use (nic.ch.vu) is suppressing it – don't know why. I updated the link above so that you can see the real thing. Cloaking is a different issue

Comment: What is a cloaking service?

Comment: @DavidG it's not yet over. +0

Comment: @nic I checked the updated url and it works. Wonder why it's not working in your phone. try adding `user-scalable=no` inside the meta content.

Comment: @nic The updated link works for me in iPhone, Android etc. What is a cloaking service?

Comment: Yeah it also works in my Android phone. Also using chrome mobile emulator.

Comment: @DavidG: Very very weird. It works now, but still not with cloaking. A cloaking service allows me to use a (in my case free) domain and hides the real address from the visitor. This works fine, but as I said, they seem to send their own HEAD, so my viewport tag is ignored and seems to be missing. Compare: http://nakt.ch.vu/stackoverflow.php
Thanks for your help

Comment: btw I'm not accepting the answer since this didn't resolve the issue, ok?

Comment: @nic Well technically this answer is correct so could be accepted, or at the very least upvoted. The other option is to close the question as it's `a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is/was the cloaking service. (nic.ch.vu).
It allows to hide the real address and camouflage it with a free and custom one.

If you choose the cloaking option, the address you typed in the address bar will never change, no matter what you click.

These services sent their own head sections, and the viewport tag gets suppressed for some reason.

If you run into the same problem, **you must disable cloaking** or use the real address.

Thanks to all posters for their help!

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that page you provided is missing the meta - viewport tag in its source.

Answer (score -2):

your meta Tag is correct, uhmm i see you only have one css link ""... Question is it repressive?  If not check out these tutorials on reponsive design helped me as well. 
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-responsive-websites-using-twitter-bootstrap/
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the links. There are 6 stylesheets. As I stated, the responsivity works well on desktop browsers. But it doesn't on phones.

Comment: DO you have media queries on in your css?