# Javascript: Overdrive URL Masking

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cloaked website (using URL masking) to pretend another URL.
When you click a link on it, the address bar URL doesn't change.

See here and try the wikipedia link: http://nakt.ch.vu/stackoverflow2.php
Compare with this: http://zhaw.warnez-services.ch/NaKt/stackoverflow2.php

For some function irrelevant to this question ([see here if you like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976375/bootstrap-responsive-not-working-on-phone-altough-viewport-included)), I need to be able to **put a link that actually changes the address bar URL**.

So the script would have to overrun the URL masking.

Javascript Location changes also don't change it – do you have an idea how to do this?

Thanks for any hints and sorry for my english :)

Comment: I know, the cloaking service puts your site to mask into an iframe

Comment: Overdrive? I had that in my old car.

Comment: Maybe 'circumnavigate' would have been more appropriate. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in an iframe/frame and you want to change the url in the address bar, than you would use

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

[MDN: window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.